# requirejs text plugin interpret html as script

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, requirejs, requirejs-text

Im using the require.js text plugin (https://github.com/requirejs/text) to load my html modules from the server.

The server has an other host so a allow coss-domain-request by useing Xhr in the require.config object.

```
text: {
  useXhr: function (url, protocol, hostname, port) {
    // allow cross-domain requests
    // remote server allows CORS

    return true;
  }
},
```

But when Im load some module the Browser try to interpret the loaded file as javascript file.

```
define([
  'text!/view_templates/header.html'], function(html){
    console.log(html) 
})
```

in the broser a get:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html:
>   "http://app-id.appspot.com/gadget/js/app/view_templates/header.html".
>   require.js:1843 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < header.html:1

Did anyone have any idea where the problem is ?

Thanks for help

Comment: I found out that overriding the useXhr method don't work. So a modify the function in the plugin self

Answer (score 0):

Took me many hours to find it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38369034/57091). useXhr doesn't get called probably because config key is not correct. It is not just `text`, it requires containing the path as well. So it should be:

```
'some/path/to/text': {
  useXhr: function (url, protocol, hostname, port) {
    return true;
  }
},
```

Or what should also work:

```
text: {
  useXhr: function (url, protocol, hostname, port) {
    return true;
  }
},
paths: {
    text: 'some/path/to/text'
}
```